# Use a subproject task in buildTasks in Gradle Release plugin

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-release-plugin

I'm configuring Gradle Release plugin `2.6.0` and want to use `buildTasks` as follows (it is in the root `build.gradle`):

```
buildTasks = ['clean', 'build', 'subprojectA:artifactoryPublish', 'subprojectB:artifactoryPublish']
```

in order to publish two jars only.

However, Gradle can't configure the project complaining as follows:

> Task with name 'subprojectA:artifactoryPublish' not found in root
>   project 'rootProject'.

How do I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you try adding a colon (`:`) before the `subprojectA` part? Task names (`clean`, `build`) will be executed for each project, for specific tasks, task paths can be used (`:<project>:<task>`).

Comment: @lu.koerfer doesn't work:c the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use the afterReleaseBuild task like described in the readme.

afterReleaseBuild.dependsOn subprojectA:artifactoryPublish

Comment: yes, this is how I've managed to work it now:) thanks for such a quick response (I saw you on Github)!